# How do I add a constant to array items in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

C code is this

```
function foo()
{
    int   i,a[10],b[10],c=2;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)  a[i] = b[i] + c; 
    printf (“%d\n”, i);
}
```

Here is my mips code:

```
.data 
a: .space   10
n: .word    1
m: .word    10
    .text
main:
        la $t1, a
    la $t2, a
    la $s3, n
    lw $t5, 0($t1)
    lw $t6, 0($t2)
    lw $t3, 0($s3)
    lw $t4, 4($s3)
    add $t0, $0, $0
foo:
    beq $t0, $t4, done
    add $t0, $t0, $t3
    add $s5, $t3, $t3
    lw $s1, 0($t5)
    lw $s2, 0($t6)
    add $s1, $s1, $s5
    sw $s1, 0($t5)
    addi $t5, $t5, 4
    addi $t6, $t6, 4
    j foo
done:
    li $v0,1
    move $a0,$t0
    syscall
    jr $ra
```

When I run it in qtspim, this error message occurs:

```
Exception occurred at PC=0x00400030
Bad address in data/stack read: 0x00000000
Attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x80000180
```

Comment: You should use qtspim to single step your code and see where it goes wrong. Also, you should comment your code especially if you want others to help. Telling us which instruction is at `PC=0x00400030` would also make sense.

Comment: What you've got at `a` initially are 10 bytes with the value zero. At `lw $t5, 0($t1)` you load a word with the value zero from `a` into register `$t5`. You then attempt to read from address zero at `lw $s1, 0($t5)`, which will result in an exception. You really need to think through what values/addresses you assign to each register and how you use them in your program.

Comment: @Michael  now I write new code by your advice but error occur in sw part....       lw $t5, 0($t1)
 lw $t6, 0($t2)
 add $t5, $t6, $s5

 sw $s1, 0($t5)   Unaligned address in store: 0x00000002
Attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x80000180

Answer (score 0):

`lw` and `sw` must use addresses that are multiples of 4.  That is the source of the "Unaligned address" error.  However, the fact that the address is "2" and not in the rage of 0x10010000 suggests that you are still confusing your "pointers" with your "variables".    Try this:  Use registers $t0 - $t4 only for "data values", and use registers $t5-$t8 for memory addresses.   That may help you avoid confusion.  Also, I find it much easier to step through and debug assembly code using MARS than SPIM.  (http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/)